# Grouping PostgreSQL Running Total Results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get a running total for 2 stores. The query that I have gets the running total for both stores together. How can I change the query to get the running total for each store separately? Below is my query. The database can be found [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/).

```
select store_id,amount, sum(amount) over (order by rental_date)
from payment
join rental on payment.rental_id=rental.rental_id
join store  on payment.customer_id=store.store_id
```

This is the result that I get:

```
store id       amont      sum
1              5.99       5.99 
1              0.99       6.98 
1              9.99       16.97 
1              4.99       21.96 
2              2.99       24.95 
1              4.99       29.94 
1              0.99       30.93 
1              3.99       34.92
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `partition by store_id` in

```
sum(amount) over (partition by store_id order by store_id, rental_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want them in different columns you do it like this

```
select
  store_id,
  amount,
  sum(case when store_id = 1 then amount else 0 end) over (order by rental_date) as store1_sum,
  sum(case when store_id = 2 then amount else 0 end) over (order by rental_date) as store2_sum,
from payment
join rental on payment.rental_id=rental.rental_id
join store  on payment.customer_id=store.store_id
```

for different rows you can partition as @BarbarosÖzhan